# Android and background tasks

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack

I'm confused on how to implement my background tasks in android and found a host of solutions using

- ThreadPools, RxJava or Coroutines
- ForegroundService
- JobScheduler, Firebase JobDispatcher,
- Alarm Manager + Broadcast receivers.
- Jetpack WorkManager

Can anyone provide the pros and cons and which situation suit which solution

Comment: I can tell you that foreground service is something that appears as a notification to the user, one that can't be removed (with out force stopping the app) so it's up to your needs if it's even relevant to use it. And if I remember correctly, Alarm Manager is kind of deprecated (JobScheduler is better than Alarm Manager) and using broadcast receivers is not really recommend, it's the slowest and uses up too many resources. This is all from memory, I might be wrong or not 100% correct